# [Crystal] rosdep cannot find all required resources

Tags: ros2, rosdep, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble with `rosdep check` on 18.04 and Crystal. I've done this:

```
pip install -U rosdep
sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
cd ~/ros2/orca_ws
. /opt/ros/crystal/setup.bash
colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+
. install/setup.bash
rosdep check orca_base
```

The output of `rosdep` is:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource orca_base
ROS path [0]=/home/clyde/ros2/orca_ws/install/orca_topside/share
```

`orca_topside` is one of the packages in my workspace. But why doesn't `rosdep` know about all of them?

As a workaround, I set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/clyde/ros2/orca_ws/install/orca_base/share
rosdep check orca_base
```

New output:

```
All system dependencies have been satisfied
ERROR[orca_base]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [orca_msgs]
    rosdep key : orca_msgs
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : bionic
    Data: <no data>
```

Do I need to manually maintain `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` for my workspace?

Thanks.

Edit -- the results of `colcon version-check`

```
colcon-argcomplete 0.3.2: up-to-date
colcon-bash 0.3.1: up-to-date
colcon-cmake 0.2.7: newer version available (0.2.8)
colcon-core 0.3.17: up-to-date
colcon-defaults 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-devtools 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-library-path 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-metadata 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-notification 0.2.6: up-to-date
colcon-output 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-package-information 0.2.2: up-to-date
colcon-package-selection 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-parallel-executor 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-pkg-config 0.1.0: up-to-date
colcon-powershell 0.3.3: up-to-date
colcon-python-setup-py 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-recursive-crawl 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-ros 0.3.7: up-to-date
colcon-test-result 0.3.1: up-to-date
colcon-zsh 0.3.1: up-to-date
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315296/%5Bcrystal%5D-rosdep-cannot-find-all-required-resources/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2019-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` needs to contain a list of the paths to **all** the packages. The way you're exporting a path to it you're not chaining onto the original value so you're losing all the other paths.

All of your exports need to have `:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` on the end of them so they are concatenated onto the original value as shown below:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/clyde/ros2/orca_ws/install/orca_base/share:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

If you create a new terminal and use this command it should hopefully fix things.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-02-11**:
Sounds like I need to set & maintain ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by hand. Somehow I thought that Colcon would do this for me. Thanks for the answer.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-02-11**:
Since `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is [deprecated](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) in favour of workspace chaining, `colcon` doesn't really do anything with it.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-11**:
~~That is incorrect.~~ `colcon-ros` does extend the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable for you: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/blob/0d1a43e6907a794b5d5a4249fb6893a39c2a1540/colcon_ros/task/catkin/build.py#L75-L77
Please check that you use the latest versions of all the `colcon` packages.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-02-11**:
Today's new thing learned! (I did look through the colcon docs but didn't find anything; obviously I was looking in the wrong place.)

If it is *not* obsolete then that wiki page should be updated with how it is actually used and managed now.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-11**:
I am sorry I missed the context of the question. The logic I referenced is only for ROS 1 / catkin packages. It would be good to open a ticket on `rosdep` for this.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-02-11**:
Ticket created: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/issues/51
Thanks!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-11**:
I was referring to this repo: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-02-12**:
Ticket created: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/660. I will mark the question as "answered." Thanks, all.